# IOS resizable images - @2x

Tags: ios, iphone, image, retina-display

I have really strange problem with resizable images. I created two files image.png (16x16) and image@2x.png (32x32), when I put my "image.png" into UIButton image in IB (editing xib) and simulate it on iphone 4(retina) and iphone 5 always appears smaller version of image. When I debug [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] always return 2, but displays smaller image. When I try manually switch the name of image to "image@2x.png" everything seems good, because loading is bigger one.
I've just checked on package content in *.app - all images are in content.
Any idea?

Edit:
I'm using storyboard with autolayout.

Comment: for using image in retina display u should named it "filename-568h@2x.png"..

Comment: The `-568h` suffix is only used for iPhone 5 launch images.. It has nothing to do with other images. Normally, only adding `@2x` before the extension should work just fine.

Comment: I have no idea whats going on. I have 2 images in my project: "xx-yy-zz.png"(16x16) and "xx-yy-zz@2x.png"(32x32), in autoulayout mode i set resizable parameters - equal or grather then in width and height

Comment: Have you definitely got the @2x version included in the file bundle?

Comment: Yes, because when I manually switch to image name with suffix @2x appears bigger one.

Comment: I tried a lot of time clear project, and reinstalling app on device

Comment: How are you verifying which image it is loading? I would make the images distinctly different (ie, fill one with red and one with blue) to be sure that you're not seeing some other effect.